# Designing Html5 Powered Shopping cart ??

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, html

I am developing a mobile shopping cart, I am following this tutorial, `http://go.developer.ebay.com/devzone/articles/building-html5-powered-shopping-cart-ios-part-1`

In this tutorial, Iam getting the products as Json into Html. For getting the product as Json iam using the following code,

```
    <?php

// simulates result of db query for categories
$categories = array();
$categories[] = array(id => 1, parent_id => 0, name => 'root');
$categories[] = array(id => 2, parent_id => 1, name => 'Compact Discs');
$categories[] = array(id => 3, parent_id => 1, name => 'Concert Souvenirs');

// simulates result of db query for products
$products = array();
$products[] = array(id => 1, category_id => 2, sku => 'CD001', price=>15.00, name => 'CD: Greatest Hits');
$products[] = array(id => 2, category_id => 2, sku => 'CD002', price=>15.00, name => 'CD: Unplugged');
$products[] = array(id => 3, category_id => 2, sku => 'CD003', price=>15.00, name => 'CD: World Tour');
$products[] = array(id => 4, category_id => 3, sku => 'PD001', price=>10.00, name => 'Souvenir Pin');
$products[] = array(id => 5, category_id => 3, sku => 'PD002', price=>10.00, name => 'Mug');
$products[] = array(id => 6, category_id => 3, sku => 'PD003', price=>20.00, name => 'Hat');
$products[] = array(id => 7, category_id => 3, sku => 'PD004', price=>12.00, name => 'Summer Tour Poster');
$products[] = array(id => 8, category_id => 3, sku => 'PD005', price=>5.00,  name => 'Concert Program');
?>
```

If I run catalog.php, I am getting Json output but with errors, like undefined constants on all the line.
AS directed by the above tutorial, I dint create any table. But I am getting just the blank screen when i access the index file.

Please help me in getting the Output.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the actual error message you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

You have to quote the string array keys in php, or you will receive warnings about undefined constants.

```
$categories[] = array('id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Compact Discs');
```